# Passive sentences : "Has been join"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Hello is it correct to say "The team has been join by William" instead of "William has join the team"?

Comment: Yes, but you need an "ed" on the end of "join". I presume it's just a spelling error on your part.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your sentences are incorrect. It should be:

> William has joined the team. (active voice)

> The team has been joined by William. (passive voice)

You could also choose another tense like:

> William joined the team. (active voice)

> The team was joined by William. (passive voice)

Comment: Note. @sachista,  that the word _joined_ used in these to examples actually represents two different grammatical forms, which are identical for most verbs, but not for "irregular" verbs. For example _William **spoke** to the team_, but _William has **spoken** to the team_ and _The team was **spoken to** by William_.